# Executor service -- not to block main program

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I am using `ExecutorService` and its blocking the main program for some time but I don't want to block the main program.

Here is the code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        ExecutorService executor = null;

        try {
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

            System.out.println("Start 1");
            Runnable task = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Start 2");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(7000);
                        System.out.println("Start 5");

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            };
            System.out.println("Start 3");

            // executor.execute(task);
            Future future = executor.submit(task);
            Object result = future.get(9, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("Start 4");

        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Start 1
Start 3
Start 2
Start 5
Start 4
finally
```

Currently it does not print `Start 4` until and unless the thread completes the execution. What I am looking for is some mechanism where we can have a timeout and the thread runs in the background and does not block the main thread?

Comment: Do you need the result? How would the main thread continue if you do need the result?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `future.get(9, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` This will wait for 9 seconds, for the submitted thread to finish. 

If you don't need the main program to wait and also don't require anything to be returned by the thread, then use the `executor.execute` call. 

Here is the updated code...

```
    ExecutorService executor = null;
    try {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        System.out.println("Start 1");
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                System.out.println("Start 2");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(7000);
                    System.out.println("Start 5");
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        };
        System.out.println("Start 3");
        executor.execute(task);
        System.out.println("Start 4");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("finally");
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know what this program is doing. 
Currently it does not print "Start 4" until and unless the thread completes the execution.
What I am looking for is some mechanism where we can have a timeout and the process does runs in background and does not block the main ? how can I alter the original program

Comment: Note the use of `executor.shutdown()` instead of `executor.shutdownNow()`. `shutdownNow` will interrupt the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are not catching timeout exception in current code before printing `Start 4` but you are catching Exception after `Start 4' line. So you are not getting desired output in case of timeout.

Change your code

from

```
 Object result = future.get(9, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

to

```
   try {
      Object result = future.get(9, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   } catch (CancellationException ce) {
       System.out.println("CancellationException ");
   } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
       System.out.println("ExecutionException ");
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
       System.out.println("InterruptedException ");
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
   }
```

With above code, you always get `Start 4` irrespective of time-out of `Future` task.

Refer to `afterExecute` method in [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) documentation page for more details.

Regarding blocking of main thread, currently you are using blocking `get()` call on `Future`. If you don't want to block your main thread, change ExecutorService to [ExecutorCompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) and use new API as per documentation above page.